# Trapezoid form with percentage units

Tags: css, reactjs

In my Next.js app (basically React) I am trying to draw a trapezoid form with Styled Components, using borders.

My code is like this:

```
const StyledContainer = styled.div`
position: relative;
border-right: 75px solid red;
border-top: 25px solid transparent;
height: 50%;
width: 75%;
display: flex;
`
```

However, for my purposes, I need the border-right and border-top properties to use percentages. But when I insert 75% instead of 75px in border-right, the trapezoid is not visible anymore.

I've tried the whole day to fix this but I didn't manage. Anyone have any idea what I need to do?

For context, the parent container has both width and height properties:

```
const SAGraph = styled.div`
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: flex-end;
background-color: hotpink;
`;
```

I have seen similar problems which were solved by using `vw` as unit, but this isn't helpful in my case, as I need to use percentages, to make sure that the trapezoid doesn't move outside the container and it uses the whole width of the container...

Edit: This is a picture of my desired output:

[image: Picture of the trapezoid]

Comment: A picture of the required output might be helpful. Have you thought of using clip-path instead of borders for this?

Comment: I must say I don't know what clip-path is... Would it work for my purposes?

Comment: Now I’ve seen what you want, yes it would, combined with a pseudo element.

Comment: Is the red bit just for decoration or is it to be an element in its own right?

Answer (score 0):

If the red section is just for decoration, you can add it to the parent element as a pseudo after element, colored red and clipped into the required shape using CSS clip-path and percentage coordinates.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.SAGraph {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  background-color: hotpink;
  position: relative;
}

.SAGraph::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 60%, 60% 50%, 60% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="SAGraph"></div>
```

If you want the red bit to be an actual child element then use the same technique direct on a child element (not on a pseudo element).